# Adding a child row to a javascript sourced data table

Tags: javascript

How do you add a child row to a table if the table is constructed using javascript sourced data?

I have not copied all of my html/script here, I just need to know in general how you would add another row below each existing row that will span the cells in the parent row.

```js
var lenders = [{
  Lender: "Bank 1",
  Amount: ["100"],
  Term: [30, 60],
  stuff: 'foo'
}, {
  Lender: "Bank 2",
  Amount: ["250"],
  Term: [60],
  stuff: 'bar'
}, {
  Lender: "Bank 3",
  Amount: ["100", "250"],
  Term: [30],
  stuff: 'baz'
}, {
  Lender: "Bank 4",
  Amount: ["100"],
  Term: [60],
  stuff: 'qux'
}, {
  Lender: "Bank 5",
  Amount: ["250"],
  Term: [30],
  stuff: 'fgfd'
}, {
  Lender: "Bank 6",
  Amount: ["100", "250"],
  Term: [30, 180],
  stuff: 'done'
}];
```

Comment: You can either insert the row into the dom, or recreate the table.

Comment: you want to add for example an object with `Lender:"Bank 1.5, ..." between Bank 1 and Bank 2?

Comment: No, so a row under for example 'bank 1' that is a child element of the bank 1 row. It should span across bank one (even if it is only one cell wide) and should show/hide when the 'bank 1' row show/hides

Answer (score 0):

Very easily, to add new item at index 1:

```
lenders.splice(1, 0, newRowObject);
```

Comment: Can you show me in a fiddle, I don't know how to do that?